# Display particular part of website

Tags: vb.net, webclient, vb.net-2010, alexa-internet

I'm going to create a tool which displays webpage rank in VB.NET.
For that I use

```
Dim str As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(("http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/" + TextBox1.Text))
```

And I just want the Global Rank of that url which I provided in `textbox1.text`

Like here, I provide example.com to check its Alexa global rank:

[image]

I just need to display the global ranking number in my VB form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz take a look at this:

```
Sub Main
    Dim str As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(("http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/example.com"))

    Dim pattern = "a href=""/siteowners/certify.+?\>(?<rank>[0-9,]+?)\<\/a\>"
    Dim r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim m As Match = r.Match(str)
    If m.Success Then
        Debug.Print("Global rank " + m.Groups(1).ToString())
        m = m.NextMatch()
        Debug.Print("Usa rank " + m.Groups(1).ToString())       
    Else
        Debug.Print("Failed")
    End If
End Sub
```

On my computer answer is

```
Global rank 8,893
Usa rank 10,060
```

This code need better error handling but I guess it is ok as a proof of concept.

UPD. Some words on how it works:

The code above uses regular expressions (please take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get started) to parse web page and extract the values you need.

On the screenshot you provided one can see that the ranks are stored in html `<a>` tag, which I identify by its href attribute, since it is the only `<a>` tag on the page, whose `href` attribute starts with string "/siteowners/certify". Hence, my regular expression matches for inner text of that tag and extracts it into match group.

Comment: Can u Explain How its Working...?

Comment: @Amitkumar please see update on the answer. I would also appreciate if you marked my answer as correct in case it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks but i have a problem to extract the value of            <font color="blue">24006 </font>